# Are there reasons NOT to upgrade the Flutter SDK minimum constraint?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I am currently developing a new app with Flutter version 1.14.6, Dart version 2.8.0, and I get the warning about the collection spread operator not being supported until version 2.3.0 when trying to use inline if-then conditions.  [As instructed here](https://flutterigniter.com/update-sdk-constraints/), I could just upgrade the minimum bound of my SDK versions in my pubspec.yaml to get rid of the warning:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
```

My question is, since this is a brand-new app being written in a version well above 2.3.0, are there any disadvantages to raising that minimum SDK bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time it might be a problem is if you are using a package or plugin that was written for an older version of Dart/Flutter and there is a significant and/or breaking change between then and now.

As an example, the `File.readAsBytesSync` method currently returns a `Uint8List` to signify that it is a list of bytes. Prior to Dart version 2.5.0, this method returned a `List<int>`, which could cause problems if a package written for 2.3 is expecting to get a `List<int>` and it gets a `Uint8List` instead.

*(The above example is somewhat contrived since `Uint8List` inherits from `List<int>` so it probably wouldn't actually cause any problems. This is the only example I could come up with off the top of my head, though, and hopefully it gets the point across.)*